# Blockquote formatting doesn't show up on mobile chat interface

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, mobile-web, blockquote

Block quotes never quite worked in the transcript, although the `>` character is still present. But, LessPop_MoreFizz of Gaming has noted that apparently, they do not appear on the chat mobile UI at all.

[image: Image of mobile chat UI where the presence of a blockquote isn't easily visible]

You could conclude where the actual block quote is by context, but I've got a convenient diagram here to show how it renders in the normal chat window.

[image: Image of block quote displaying properly in normal chat]

If the little dotted line can't be shown in the mobile chat UI, can we at least have the `>` character preserved like how it appears in the transcript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Now if only everything was as easily fixed as that.

[image]